# Particle System/movement in Dynamo, using Python Scripting

Tags: python, processing, p5.js, particle-system

So i am trying to translate/re-create this script below, which is in Java (p5 /P5.js), to PythonScript in Dynamo:

[image]

and my attempt so far looks like this:

[image]

I just want to know if I am going about this the right way? i feel like im not doing the def init correctly? should it be (eg): self.location = location, and then on another line i describe location?
Also, in the processing/java script, the Particle is a class which is then referenced in main script tab… so can i just write out the class Particle first and then do the main code?

Many thanks, i’m trying to learn and any advice/feedback would help me lots :)

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)